# Creating multiple curves using seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe called `Prices1`, which I have pasted below. I would like to plot all the columns against the index in `seaborn`.

Please note that in this example I have four columns but in other problems I will have different number of columns.

```
    AMZN    BABA    COST    WMT
716 0.1256  1.62168 1.1572  1.35279
717 0.117824    1.6236  1.19329 1.36988
718 0.120359    1.65928 1.2042  1.38496
719 0.119176    1.64181 1.18629 1.39703
720 0.123233    1.67813 1.20476 1.36385
```

I have tried to use this but I keep getting an error:

```
sns.lineplot(data= Prices1.iloc[:, :2])
```

The error is as follows:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-123-d006d5480255> in <module>
----> 1 sns.lineplot(data= df.iloc[:, :2])

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seaborn/_decorators.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     44             )
     45         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 46         return f(**kwargs)
     47     return inner_f
     48 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seaborn/relational.py in lineplot(x, y, hue, size, style, data, palette, hue_order, hue_norm, sizes, size_order, size_norm, dashes, markers, style_order, units, estimator, ci, n_boot, seed, sort, err_style, err_kws, legend, ax, **kwargs)
    694     p._attach(ax)
    695 
--> 696     p.plot(ax, kwargs)
    697     return ax
    698 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seaborn/relational.py in plot(self, ax, kws)
    469         # Loop over the semantic subsets and add to the plot
    470         grouping_vars = "hue", "size", "style"
--> 471         for sub_vars, sub_data in self.iter_data(grouping_vars, from_comp_data=True):
    472 
    473             if self.sort:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seaborn/_core.py in iter_data(self, grouping_vars, reverse, from_comp_data)
    979                 grouping_keys.append(self.var_levels.get(var, []))
    980 
--> 981             iter_keys = itertools.product(*grouping_keys)
    982             if reverse:
    983                 iter_keys = reversed(list(iter_keys))

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the data in float format? Try this to confirm. `Prices1.info()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the format of data in your `Prices1` dataframe with:

```
print(Prices1.info())
```

You should something like:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 5 entries, 716 to 720
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   AMZN    5 non-null      float64
 1   BABA    5 non-null      float64
 2   COST    5 non-null      float64
 3   WMT     5 non-null      float64
dtypes: float64(4)
memory usage: 200.0 bytes
None
```

Pay attention to `Dtype` column: all of your columns should be `float64` type. Otherwise those values are not recognized by `seaborn` as numbers.
If that is the case, you can convert columns type with:

```
Prices1 = Prices1.apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

Then you can plot data trends with:

```
sns.lineplot(data = Prices1)
```

[image]

Comment: Big help. So detailed explaination. Also Thank You for showing me how to convert data from object to float!